# How to set up Network on Rancher UI for multi workload app

Tags: networking, containers, rancher, workload

I have deployed several workload containers from dockerhub to Rancher. Now I need  them connected through a network. How do I go about this? I have a Load balancer set up. I think a network can be set up  through load balancer in the Rancher UI?

Currently I have five workloads under one namespace (webapp-9):

```
webapp-9-apache
webapp-9-php
webapp-9-mysql
webapp-9-solr
webapp-9-phpmyadmin
```

Following error occurs when pullin up webapp-9-apache workload in browser:

```
Proxy Error
Reason: DNS lookup failure for: php
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: path/to/apache/Dockerfile
    image: user:webapp-9-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./http:/path/to/web/
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: path/to/php/Dockerfile
    image: user:webapp-9-php
    volumes:
      - ./http:/path/to/folder/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: path/to/mysql/Dockerfile
    image: user:webapp-9-mysql
    command: mysqld --sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/path/to/mysql
      - .docker/mysql/config:/path/to/conf.d
  solr:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
    image: user:webapp-9-solr
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"   
    volumes:
      - ./solr_data:/path/to/solr
    command:
      - solr-precreate
      - gettingstarted  
  phpmyadmin:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: path/to/phpmyadmin/Dockerfile
    image: user:webapp-9-phpmyadmin
    ports: 
      - 8090:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - PMA_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=200M
```

Answer (score 0):

All workloads need to be under the same Namespace (which they already were) and the workloads need to be named according to the services in the docker-composer.yml file.
e.g. drupal-9-spintx-php -> php